# Using an IF THEN loop with nested JSON files in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am currently writing a program which uses the ComapaniesHouse API to return a json file containing information about a certain company.

I am able to retrieve the data easily using the following commands:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/COMPANY-NO/filing-history', auth=('API-KEY', ''))

data = r.json()
```

With that information I can do an awful lot, however I've ran into a problem which I was hoping you guys could possible help me with. What I aim to do is go through every nested entry in the json file and check if the value of certain keys matches certain criteria, if the values of 2 keys match a certain  criteria then other code is executed.

One of the keys is the date of an entry, and I would like to ignore results that are older than a certain date, I have attempted to do this with the following:

```
date_threshold = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)``



for each in data["items"]:
        date = ['date']
        type = ['type']
     if date < date_threshold and type is "RM01":
        print("wwwwww")
```

In case it isn't clear, what I'm attempting to do (albeit very badly) is assign each of the entries to a variable, which then gets tested against certain criteria.

Although this doesn't work, python spits out a variable mismatch error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < datetime.date()
```

Which makes me think the date is being stored as a string, and so I can't compare it to the datetime value set earlier, but when I check the API documentation (https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/company/company_number/filing-history/filingHistoryItem-resource.html), it says clearly that the 'date' entry is returned as a date type.

What am I doing wrong, its very clear that I'm extremely new to python given what I presume is the atrocity of my code, but in my head it seems to make at least a little sense. In case none of this clear, I basically want to go through all the entries in the json file, and the if the date and type match a certain description, then other code can be executed (in this case I have just used random text).

Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need anything cleared up.

:)

EDIT

After tweaking my code to the below:

```
for each in data["items"]:
        date = each['date']
        type = each['type']
     if date is '2016-09-15' and type is "RM01":
        print("wwwwww")
```

The code executes without any errors, but the words aren't printed, even though I know there is an entry in the json file with that exact date, and that exact type, any thoughts?

SOLUTION:

Thanks to everyone for helping me out, I had made a couple of very basic errors, the code that works as expected is below::

```
for each in data["items"]:
    date = each['date']
    typevariable = each['type']

    if date == '2016-09-15' and typevariable == "RM01":
        print("wwwwww")
```

This prints the word "wwwwww" 3 times, which is correct seeing as there are 3 entries in the JSON that fulfil those criteria.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Your `for` loop is incorrect. You would need `for each in data['items']: date = each['date']` and so on. Essentially putting `each` in front of `['date']` and `'[type']`. You are assigning each JSON object in turn to the name "each".

Comment: `date = ['date']` and the line after don't make sense, you're making a list variable which is holding a string. Did you want to do `date = each['date']`?

Comment: Hey @mike.k, thanks for comments! I've made those changes and I got an type error but this type with str() instead of list(). So i thought why not just test it out and put - if date is '2016-09-15' and... - but nothing happened. The code was executed successfully but my words weren't printed, even though I know there is an entry in the json with that exact date and that exact type. Any advice?

Comment: `type` is a python builtin so you should avoid that as a variable name as it can lead to unpredictable things happening. Also, the indentation in your question is wonky: is your `if` in line with the word `type` in the line above it?

Comment: You don't use is to test equality,  use `if date == '2016-09-15' and type  == "RM01":`

Comment: @roganjosh, Hi thanks for the comment, will change the variable name and get back to you, and yes the code in the question is printed incorrectly, the words 'each', 'date', 'type' and 'if' are all on top of eachother

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, perfect thats done the job, must seem like an absolutely idiotic mistake but I'm still learning! haha, thanks again everyone, will include the answers in my question for others

Comment: No need to edit the question to include the answers, you can write your own answer and accept at a later date. That way the question is clearly closed when people look down the list of questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @roganjosh, sorry didn't realise I'm new to this, will do that now

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert your date variable to a datetime type using [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

You are comparing a list type variable `date` with datetime type variable `date_threshold`.

Comment: Hi @techidiot, thanks for the reply, please see my answer to the comments above